# rowSums only positive values in subsetted dataframe

Tags: r

I have a df, that needs to be subsetted (by a column name variable). I'm having trouble because I need to create 2 calculations:

1. sum the columns predefined in the variable, if they are > 0
2. count the columns predefined in the variable, if they are > 0

My actual df contains 500k rows, and 40 columns, but I subset this using:

```
BD[, var_names]
  may_18 jun_18 jul_18 ago_18 sep_18
   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1   NA     6.78   NA     4.88   NA  
2   42.9 262.   -198.   78.5    53.2
3   24.0  21.7    28.4  25.4    14.6
4  222   242.    284.  259.    283. 
5    0     0       0     0       0  
6  281.  486.    500.  485.    227.
```

By now, I've used

```
rowSums(BD[, var_names][which(var_names > 0)], na.rm = TRUE)
```

But it isn't working well.
Also, I've tried this for the count:

```
rowSums(BD[, var_names] > 0, na.rm = TRUE)
```

The expected output for the table, is something like

```
SUM COUNT
11,66   2
436,6   4
114,1   5
1290    5
0   0
1979    5
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In base R one approach could be:

```
var_names <- c("may_18", "jun_18", "jul_18", "ago_18", "sep_18")

cbind(SUM = apply(df[var_names], 1, function(x) sum(x[x > 0], na.rm = TRUE)),
      COUNT = rowSums(df[var_names] > 0, na.rm = TRUE))

      SUM COUNT
1   11.66     2
2  436.60     4
3  114.10     5
4 1290.00     5
5    0.00     0
6 1979.00     5
```

Or using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  select(var_names) %>%
  transmute(SUM = rowSums(mutate_all(., ~if_else(.x < 0, NA_real_, .x)), na.rm = TRUE),
         COUNT = rowSums(. > 0, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Works amazing!. Finally in base R, I've changed the cbind part to directly add the calculation to the df.